# HTML and PHP post value is limited

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I want to upload 2 table from local sql server 2000 to hosted mysql. First table has 17 columns and 680 rows, and the other 10 columns and 8071 rows.

I tried offline first using xampp mysql and it works, all the data inserted to the new table in mysql when i checked in phpmyadmin. And because of SQL Server 2000 was not supported in my web-hosting provider, so I decided to upload only the php files to catch the post values that runs on localhost xampp then insert to hosted mysql server. That works, but limited to 59 row on first table and 100 row on second table. The rest of row is failed to insert. I tried to check print in php for row 200+ and nothing show up. that means php didn't catch all the row.

So my question, Is it true that a hosted php limited for getting value?
And what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size#2184541)

Comment: I have found php.ini in xampp php folder, but that already set to 128M both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. Do I have to change that setting in my web-hosting cpanel? how to change that?

Comment: @laurentiuskevin it depends on hosting, please contact somebody from your hosting

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I have try to change php.ini value in cpanel and it works. thank you so much for the guide.